# Save 3 images from a Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am making a collage type application. The problem I have is that I have a button to save the 3 images of the collage, but only one saves me. Thank you very much in advance.

The button code is this

```
@IBAction func saveImage(_ sender: Any) {
        let imageData = ImageViewOne.image!.pngData()
      
    let compresedImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compresedImage!, nil, nil, nil)
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Saved", message: "Your image has been saved", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    }
```

Comment: Could you add a little bit more information or screenshot, So that we can understand, what it the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand question correctly - you have 3 `UIImageView`s and want to save them as they are on screen.

So simplest solution will be to put them into `UIView` container and then render `UIView`'s content to image

```swift
public extension UIView {
    func asImage() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for u answer. Yes, I want to save a photo with 3 ImageView. The problem is that what you tell me I do not know how to implement.

Comment: @LucaToniBastian well this is basics. Not sure how to explain this. if `ImageViewOne.superiew?.subviews` will show you only 3 UIImageViews then you can try `ImageViewOne.superiew?.asImage()` to get your combined image. if not - you should modify UI hierarchy as I described in post above and I don't think I will be able to explain it better.